# laravel Eloquent sync() method, Executing multiple INSERT queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my application i have 3 table. `product` , `properties` , `product_property`. base on the eloquent ralationship conventions, i related this tables into many to many relation.
into the `store controller` i need to sync product properties :
`$product->properties()->sync($properties_array))`.
but laravel Eloquent `sync()` method, Executing multiple INSERT queries.
i think this is not optimize.
how can i fix or optimize this queries ?

[screenshot of queries](https://s22.postimg.cc/afkgsff4h/Untitled.png)

Comment: what is in `$properties_array` ? add your code

Comment: @rkj Property::all();

Comment: try `$product->properties()->sync(Property::pluck('id'));`

Comment: @rkj actually problem is the count of queries. every id run into a query, this is not optimaize